Does my AWS Lambda app need a serverless.template file if I'm using the CDK?
I have a .NET 8 Core Minimal API which I have converted to a Lambda by adding builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.RestApi); to the initialization code in my Program.cs Main method.
I have also created some CDK code to bootstrap/deploy the infrastructure to my AWS instance (in my case I am using LocalStack in Docker rather than a live AWS environment).  I am using Typescript for this, because that is what my organization's DevOps team prefers.
My \lib\*cdk-stack.ts file looks like this (I have replaced org-specific app names/namespaces with generic names to protect the privacy of my org):
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Lambda } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ses-actions';
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

export class MyFunctionCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

      const functionProps: lambda.FunctionProps = {
          runtime: lambda.Runtime.DOTNET_8,
          code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('../MyFunctionAssemblyName/bin/Release/net8.0/publish'),
          handler: 'MyFunctionAssemblyName',
          timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(600)
      };

      new lambda.Function(this, "MyFunction", functionProps);
  }
}


And my \bin\*cdk.ts file is defined as follows:
#!/usr/bin/env node
import 'source-map-support/register';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { MyFunctionCdkStack } from '../lib/my-app-name.cdk-stack';

const app = new cdk.App();
new MyFunctionCdkStack(app, 'MyFunctionCdkStack', {
  /* If you don't specify 'env', this stack will be environment-agnostic.
   * Account/Region-dependent features and context lookups will not work,
   * but a single synthesized template can be deployed anywhere. */

  /* Uncomment the next line to specialize this stack for the AWS Account
   * and Region that are implied by the current CLI configuration. */
  // env: { account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION },

  /* Uncomment the next line if you know exactly what Account and Region you
   * want to deploy the stack to. */
  // env: { account: '123456789012', region: 'us-east-1' },

  /* For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html */
});

I am able to deploy this stack to LocalStack, but only if my main project contains a properly-populated serverless.template file.  However, it is my understanding that the CDK, if properly configured, obviates the need for serverless.template.  Is this true?  Or do I still need serverless.template?
If I am indeed able to do away with serverless.template and instead define all the infrastructure in my CDK code, how do I do this?  In other words, what are the CDK Typescript equivalents to the properties defined in serverless.template?
For reference, I have included my serverless.template here (again, with identifying information obfuscated):
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "An AWS Serverless Application. This template is partially managed by Amazon.Lambda.Annotations (v1.2.0.0).",
  "Resources": {
    "MyFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "MyFunctionAssemblyName",
        "Runtime": "dotnet8",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 600,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [
          "AWSLambda_FullAccess"
        ],
        "Environment": {
          "Variables": {
            "POWERTOOLS_SERVICE_NAME": "MyService",
            "POWERTOOLS_LOG_LEVEL": "Info",
            "POWERTOOLS_LOGGER_CASE": "PascalCase",
            "POWERTOOLS_TRACER_CAPTURE_RESPONSE": true,
            "POWERTOOLS_TRACER_CAPTURE_ERROR": true,
            "POWERTOOLS_METRICS_NAMESPACE": "MyServiceFunction"
          }
        },
        "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
              "Type": "Api",
              "Properties": {
                  "Path": "/{proxy+}/path",
                  "Method": "ANY"
              }
          },              
          "RootResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/path",
              "Method": "GET"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
      "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
      }
    }
  }
}

To reiterate: my question is whether or not it's possible to eliminate the need for serverless.template by defining everything in my CDK Typescript files.

serverless.template is for the AWS SAM and has nothing to do with AWS CDK.
You should use either AWS SAM or AWS CDK. So, if you're using CDK, you can definitely delete the serverless.template file.
To deploy API Gateway along with Lambda hosting a .NET API, you can refer Create an Amazon API Gateway REST API to AWS Lambda pattern that I published on ServerlessLand, where you can refer the CDK code for the same. The CDK code is in .NET, but you can easily write TypeScript equivalent.

The CDK deployment works on AWS cloud, but I have not tested it against LocalStack.

